# How to get the value of the selected radio button?

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button

I would like to create 2 different groups of radio buttons. The user would select one option from either group. There would be a function that would get the values(strings) from the selected radio buttons and then print them. Here's my code but it doesn't work (i'm new to python).

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
btn1 = "lol"
btn2 = "lel"
def funkcija():
    n = entry1.get()
    m = "null"
    X = btn1.get()
    Y = btn2.get()
    print("%s %s je %s %s." % (n, X, m, Y))


theLabel = Label(root, text="Vnesite količino in izberite prvo valuto.")
theLabel.grid(row=0, columnspan=3)

gumb1=Radiobutton(root,text="Euro",value = "euro",variable = "btn1").grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W)
gumb2=Radiobutton(root,text="Dolar",value = "dolar",variable = "btn1").grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W)
gumb3=Radiobutton(root,text="Funt",value = "funt",variable = "btn1").grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=W)

label3= Label(root, text="Izberite drugo valuto.")
label3.grid(row=6, columnspan=3)

label35= Label(root)
label35.grid(row=5, columnspan=3)

gumb4=Radiobutton(root,text="Euro",value = "euro",variable = "btn2").grid(row=7, column=1, sticky=W)
gumb5=Radiobutton(root,text="Dolar",value = "dolar",variable = "btn2").grid(row=8, column=1, sticky=W)
gumb6=Radiobutton(root,text="Funt",value = "funt",variable = "btn2").grid(row=9, column=1, sticky=W)

label1 = Label(root, text="Količina:")
label1.grid(row=1, sticky=E)
entry1 = Entry(root)
entry1.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W)

go = Button(root, text="Izračun", fg="white", bg="black", command=funkcija)
go.grid(row=10, columnspan=3)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Could You write what works? Could You trim the code to something smaller?

Comment: It has already been solved :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your radio button, analyze the parameters that you are passing:

```
gumb1 = Radiobutton(root,
                    text = "Euro",
                    value = "Euro",
                    variable = "btn2"
```

The parameters `value` and `variable` are what stores the data of the radio button. You've set your `value` option correctly. The interpreter will automatically set the `variable` with the `value` when the radio button is selected.

But here's where your issue is:

```
variable = "btn2"
```

`"btn2"` is a string. Not very useful though, is it? In fact, you're trying to perform methods on it that don't even exist. Such as here:

```
def funkcija():
    X = btn2.get()
```

In fact, taking this information, you almost got there!

At the top of your script, you need to set `btn2` to Tkinter's `StringVar`,  like so:

```
from tkinter import *
btn1 = StringVar()
btn2 = StringVar()
```

Now that's done, let's change our parameters in our radio buttons.

```
gumb1 = Radiobutton(root,
                text = "Euro",
                value = "Euro",
                variable = btn2
```

Now, Tkinter will automatically update the variable when it is selected. To get the value, do the same that you had done in your `funkcija`.

```
X = btn2.get()
```

And then the value of btn2 (which was updated by the radio buttons) will not be read, and stored into the variable `X`.

Comment: Thanks so much! There's one more question. Why do I have to set the variables to StringVar below root = Tk() ? If i put them above root = Tk() it doesn't work.

Comment: @Zoxx 
The StringVar set below root = Tk() is associated with the root window. If it is placed above root = Tk() it is not associated with any window and thus will not work.